# Authorization bearer - Wordpress REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

Please i try to make REST API in Wordpress using the plugins **WP OAuth Server** and after create a new Client in **Oauth server** and generate a new **access token**, i could not connect by the Authorization in the header

```
function register_api_hooks2() {
    register_rest_route(
        'wp/v2/', '/beacon_products',
        array(
            'methods'  => POST,
            'callback' => 'beacon_products',
            'args' => [
                'id'
            ],
        )
    );
    function beacon_products($request){
        global $wpdb;
        $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

        if ( empty( $current_user_id ) ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'rest_not_logged_in', __( 'You are not currently logged in.' ), array( 'status' => 401 ) );
        }


        $result = array();
/*      filter_var($_POST['beacon_id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)*/
        if(isset($_POST['eid']) && !empty($_POST['eid']) && isset($_POST['uid']) && !empty($_POST['uid'])){         
            try {
        /* code  */
                }else{
                    return new WP_Error( 'Beacon introuvable','Aucun beacon associé au ses paramétres', array( 'status' => 404 ) );
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return new WP_Error( 'Une erreur s\'est produite','Une erreur au niveau de serveur', array( 'status' => 500 ) );
            }
        }else{
            return new WP_Error( 'parametre manquant','eid ou bien uid introuvable', array( 'status' => 403 ) );
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: 0 means user is not logged in

Comment: but the Authorization access code is good

Comment: You need to share your code and more information about what you have tried and what responses you get

Comment: Just a mint, i will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Lots to do here. You really need to read the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/)

You should use the permissions callback in your initial function and `current_user_can` instead of `get_current_user_id` to determine whether or not to run the callback function.

You should return your callback output using `return new WP_REST_Response( $result, 200 );`